# Jenkins Maven integration failed

Tags: maven, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with Maven. Through terminal I am able to execute the Maven command (`clean install`). But from Jenkins it fails.

Getting following error:

```
   <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /Users/krishna/eclipse-workspace/Tools/LearnBroswserStack/pom.xml clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building BrowserStackDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ BrowserStackDemo ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/krishna/eclipse-workspace/Tools/LearnBroswserStack/target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.090 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-04T16:17:27+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/190M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project BrowserStackDemo:** Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/krishna/eclipse-workspace/Tools/LearnBroswserStack/target/.DS_Store -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/krishna/eclipse-workspace/Tools/LearnBroswserStack/pom.xml to BrowserStack/BrowserStackDemo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/BrowserStackDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
/Users/krishna/eclipse-workspace/Tools/LearnBroswserStack/pom.xml is not inside /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MavenJenkinsIntegration1/Users/krishna/eclipse-workspace/Tools/LearnBroswserStack/; will archive in a separate pass
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Note:

I am not using any server like Tomcat. My problem is not able to delete the `target` folder from Jenkins, when ever I taken a clean build, `target` folder will create newly, so I am unable to give the access for the `target` folder.

Comment: Have you looked at http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException ?

Comment: Yes , my problem  is not able to delete the target folder from jenkins,when ever I taken a clean build, target folder is newly created ,so I am unable to give the access for the target folder.

Comment: On my Windows(7) the Jenkins service runs under the [_LocalSystem_ account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) by default. _LocalSystem_ has _full control_ on any sub-folder under my user's folder by default. Did you change or check the settings for your Jenkins service and your Eclipse workspace project folder(s) already?

Comment: Re: "_when ever I taken a clean build, target folder will create newly, so I am unable to give the access for the target folder_" – There is a checkbox  [☑ _Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent_](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7) in the _Security_ → _Advanced..._ dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkins executor is unable to delete the target folder of project . The error statements points it out clearly.

```
*[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project BrowserStackDemo:** Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/krishna/eclipse-workspace/Tools/LearnBroswserStack/target/.DS_Store -> [Help 1]
```

Such error occurs when the access to file is denied at the OS filesystem level OR the target folder's files are already being used somewhere in some other process and they are left in OPEN state. Try deleting the target folder manually.

Comment: I am able to delete the folder through terminal, but problem is not able to delete the target folder from jenkins,when ever I taken a clean build, target folder is newly created ,so I am unable to give the access for the target folder,could you please help me to kickoff this issue.

Comment: maybe you have  committed the target folder in your code repository. Check and ensure that target folder is NOT committed and pushed in your repo.